# Which NumberFormat string for DBGrid?

Tags: vb6, formatting, dbgrid

I maintain a VB6 application that uses a DBGrid. I want to format a column in such a way that 18.0 becomes 18, but 18.33 becomes 18.3 How do I do that? A reference would be even more helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
The answer is "0.#"
See [here](http://www.apostate.com/vb-format-syntax) for more details
EDIT: Unfortunately this may work for some Datagrids, but not for the one I am using. That will display 18. in stead of 18